# Python gives syntax error but there is no mistake?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, user-defined-functions

Can someone say why python doesn't allow this?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import win32api,win32con,os,time,sys
x_pad =464
y_pad =235

def tik():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    print "Click.".decode('utf-8').encode(sys.stdout.encoding)        #completely optional. But nice for debugging purposes.
def basilitut():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    print 'Hold'.decode('utf-8').encode(sys.stdout.encoding)


def birak():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    print 'Release.'.decode('utf-8').encode(sys.stdout.encoding)

def mousePos(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1])



def oyun():
    #Ses kes
    mousePos((163, 251))
    tik()
    time.sleep(.1)
    #Play butonu
    mousePos((161, 127))
    tik()
    time.sleep(.1)

    #Iphone
    mousePos((149, 267))
    tik()
    time.sleep(.1)

    #Merhaba
    mousePos((373, 314))
    tik()
    time.sleep(.1)

    #Goal
    mousePos((163, 251))
    tik()
    time.sleep(.1)
```

> File "C:\Users\Doruk\Desktop\Python\Bot\code.py", line 27
>
> def oyun():
>
> ```
>   ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

And when I remove that def oyun(): blablabla

> File "C:\Users\Doruk\Desktop\Python\Bot\code.py", line 24
>
> ```
>                                                             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

It just gives the error with blank line.

And when I delete

```
def mousePos(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1])
```

It works but I can't make my program without them.

Comment: When debugging syntax errors, it can often help to interpret it as "There's something else I was expecting to see before this `def foo(...`"

Comment: Errors are reported on the line they are *detected*, which is not necessarily the line at fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the code immediately above the reported error:

```
def mousePos(cord):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1])
```

You're missing a closing parentheses.

Comment: Wow, sorry for that. I thought it was same like type error etc. and shows the exact position of it. I learned something new. Thank you.

Comment: The error is caused by the fact that Python allows you to continue expressions to the next line when parentheses are open. So Python is not complaining that you didn't close your parentheses; that is perfectly valid and you may have done it on purpose. It's complaining because you tried to put a function definition inside parentheses and it's not valid there. That's why it gives you an error on the `def` line.

Answer (score 2):

You sure there's no syntax error?

```
win32api.SetCursorPos((x_pad + cord[0], y_pad + cord[1])
                     12                                2  1???
```

The line that a syntax error is reported on is not necessary where the syntax error is. It's merely the first place where an earlier syntax error caused the parser to realize that something's wrong.

Comment: Wow sorry I didn't know it gives syntax error where it first sees, I thought it was same with type error etc. that shows the exact error.

Comment: type errors are usually right on the very same line, when you do something like `int = string`. but with missing punctuation like you have, that's not necessarily an error RIGHT THERE, because the code could pick up on the next line and be entirely correct.

Comment: I'm new to this thing sorry for this dumb question :(